# trying to translate a math formula into python

Tags: python, math

I'm rather new to python I'm writing this program that calculates the falling time of a box using this simple formula:

h-0.5gT^2 = 0

h = 100
g = 9.8
T = ?

Where T is the time it takes (4.5 sec) On paper, I can easily solve for T but I'm not sure how to translate this into python I don't know if there's a formula that can give me the value of T with the inputs I already have or what

Comment: What did you try? Show your code, even if it didn't work. Maybe operator precedence is tripping you up? See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import math
T = math.sqrt(h / (0.5 * g))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/10-Symbolic-Math/10.06-Solving-Equations/) you could use the following code:

```
from sympy import symbols, solve

T = symbols('T')
h=100
g=9.8

expr = h-0.5*g*(T*T)

sol=solve(expr)
print(sol)
```

As an alternative you do the operations yourself by writing (as @yair koskas wrote):

```
T = math.sqrt(h / (0.5 * g))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking how to solve for T.

T = ((2 * h) / g) ** 0.5

So start Python interpreter and type the following

```
h = 100
g = 9.81
T = ((2 * h) / g) ** 0.5
print(T)
```